# how to filter foreign key in django form without passing foreign key value?

Tags: django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys

I have created two models in my django project AddStudent and Fee Entry as shown below.

**models.py**

```py
class AddStudent(models.Model):
    enrollment_no = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    course = models.ForeignKey(CourseMaster, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    category= models.ForeignKey(CatMaster, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    admission_year = models.IntegerField(('year'), choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    college = models.ForeignKey(CollegeMaster, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(BranchMaster,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    current_semester = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    student_contact = models.BigIntegerField()
    parent_contact = models.BigIntegerField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('add_student:index')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.enrollment_no) + ' - ' + self.student_name

class FeeEntry(models.Model):

    student = models.ForeignKey(AddStudent,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    fee_detail = models.ForeignKey(FeeMaster,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    fee_sem = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    payment_date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    pay_method = models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES)
    cheque_no = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null=True, blank=True)
    bank_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ' - ' + str(self.student) + ' - ' + self.student.student_name
```

Now when user search particular student for example student id = 1 than student profile page will open and there is another button addfee. My problem is when user click on add fee all 500 student list is appear in dropdown list. i want to create fee for searched student only.

**forms.py**

```py
from django import forms
from .models import FeeEntry, AddStudent
from bootstrap_modal_forms.mixins import PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin

class FeeForm(PopRequestMixin, CreateUpdateAjaxMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FeeEntry
        fields = ['student', 'fee_detail', 'fee_sem', 'payment_date', 'pay_method','cheque_no','bank_name']
```

above is my forms.py file where field 'student' will generate all 500 student list. I want only selected student for example enrollment_no=1 when user is on enrollment_no 1's page.

**views.py**

```
class FeeCreateView(PassRequestMixin, SuccessMessageMixin,
                         generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'add_student/create_fee.html'
    form_class = FeeForm
    success_message = 'Success: Book was created.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('add_student:detail')
```

**urls.py**

```
path('create/<int:pk>', views.FeeCreateView.as_view(), name='create_fee'),
```

Can anyone tell me what changes are required in this code? or can you share link of similar example like this?

Answer (score 0):

The FeeForm does not know which student you want to relate it with. Because of that, it is showing you a dropdown asking which student you want to assign to the FeeEntry instance.

Remove 'student' from the form and send the form to the view. when the user submits the form, use the form_valid (form.is_valid if you are using FBV) method to assign the student to the fee_entry instance.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    fee_entry = form.save(commit=False)
    fee_entry.student = AddStudent.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['student_id'])
    fee_entry.save()
```

Also make sure to send the student_id in the url. You can even send it as a POST parameter(check out how to retrieve parameter from a POST request) using a hidden field in the form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am beginner to django. I understood your answer but when I tried this changes everything is mess up.